# How can I use ZF1 $this->action in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

My problem is that in ZF2 missing Action View Helper.
How can I use for example in layout.phtml (or in other view)?

```
ZF1: $this->action("index", "index") // call IndexController indexAction
```

ZF2: ???

How can i solve this?

---

The problem solved!!! ;)
http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/?p=223

Comment: Here's the current link for the article:  http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to write a custom helper like this:

https://github.com/AlloVince/eva-engine/blob/master/vendor/Eva/View/Helper/Action.php

Maybe you need to change the namespace to fit your project, Then register this helper as a invokable helper service in your module config file:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'action' => 'Eva\View\Helper\Action',
    ),  
),
```

Then you could call any controller action in view like this:

```
$this->action('Engine\Controller\PagesController', 'indexAction');
```

---

**EDIT**:

OP found a nice solution here: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/?p=223.  Since he didn't post it as an answer, other users might miss it.

Comment: Your helper is not direct analog to `Action` helper in zf1. It invoked whole dispatch process. As for registering controller as invokable from your helper - that is really bad practice.

Comment: Actually I think "call a controller action in view" itself is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

`Action` view helper was not recommended in zf1 and was completely removed in zf2 as bad practice. You should consider changing application design to not rely on such behaviour.