# Zend Framework 2 - Calling an Action within a View

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use ZF1 $this->action in ZF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758561/how-can-i-use-zf1-this-action-in-zf2)

I'm working with PHP since some years ago, I know OOP very well, but I'm a newbie with Zend Framework 2, I'm having some troubles with its concepts.

I'm trying to develop a website, already done, but now with ZF2.

One of my biggest problems are with Layouts/Views (I already know the difference between them).

In that website, there is a sidebar menu that is dynamically generated (content pulled from DB...let's call sideBarGenAction inside CategoriesController). And I need to display that in every single page (inside a Layout template). So, that's my doubts: how to do that, without calling that Action (sideBarGenAction) inside every other Action?

If the sidebar had static content, I could use $this->partial, but it has dynamic content, and partial needs vars to be passed to.

I suppose I could create a ViewHelper, but it doesn't make much sense (since it isn't a Widget, it's a business rule inside a Model....if I had to create a ViewHelper for everything I would need to be called "within" a View, I wouldn't need a MVC framework).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your model should have reuseable unit testable methods to grab pieces of data, could be string, objects, arrays, etc.  This is where there is logic to properly handle data so it's useable in a way that makes sense and again, can be unit tested.

In the controller, you instantiate an instance of that model and use the method you need to get the data you want to use.  You then pass it to the view.  Now this could be in the action itself, or, you could create a reusable method that does this and returns the data so other actions could also use it.  If this is something that could also be used in other contorllers, then you should probably create an action helper that the controller uses.... you get the point... there are a lot of ways to architect the same thing, depending on how focused you are on reusable code.

To pass data from the controller to the view in zf1, you need to do it like this

```
$this->view->whateverItIsCalled = $someValueOrArrayTypeThing;
```

then in the view just use it, echo it, etc. like `$this->whateverItIsCalled.`

In zf2, it's like this

```
namespace Content\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ArticleController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function viewAction()
    {
        // get the article from the persistence layer, etc...

        $view = new ViewModel();

        $articleView = new ViewModel(array('article' => $article));
        $articleView->setTemplate('content/article');

        $primarySidebarView = new ViewModel();
        $primarySidebarView->setTemplate('content/main-sidebar');

        $secondarySidebarView = new ViewModel();
        $secondarySidebarView->setTemplate('content/secondary-sidebar');

        $sidebarBlockView = new ViewModel();
        $sidebarBlockView->setTemplate('content/block');

        $secondarySidebarView->addChild($sidebarBlockView, 'block');

        $view->addChild($articleView, 'article')
             ->addChild($primarySidebarView, 'sidebar_primary')
             ->addChild($secondarySidebarView, 'sidebar_secondary');

        return $view;
    }
}
```

and the view will use it just like you used stuff before in zf1 e.g.

```
<?php // "content/article" template ?>
<div class="row content">
    <?php echo $this->article ?>

    <?php echo $this->sidebar_primary ?>

    <?php echo $this->sidebar_secondary ?>
</div>

<?php // "content/article" template ?>
    <!-- This is from the $articleView View Model, and the "content/article"
         template -->
    <article class="span8">
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml('article') ?>
    </article>

<?php // "content/main-sidebar" template ?>
    <!-- This is from the $primarySidebarView View Model, and the
         "content/main-sidebar" template -->
    <div class="span2 sidebar">
        sidebar content...
    </div>

<?php // "content/secondary-sidebar template ?>
    <!-- This is from the $secondarySidebarView View Model, and the
         "content/secondary-sidebar" template -->
    <div class="span2 sidebar pull-right">
        <?php echo $this->block ?>
    </div>

<?php // "content/block template ?>
        <!-- This is from the $sidebarBlockView View Model, and the
            "content/block" template -->
        <div class="block">
            block content...
        </div>
```

You can see how you instantiated a new view model, then passed things not only to the view, but you can also designate more specific partials, which is different.

Anyway, hope that helps you out. Basically, long story short, ZF2 improves performance over ZF1 for a few reasons, but reducing overhead is an important one.  A lot of frameworks, most in fact, do this because you only need what you need when you need it.

Comment: that is ZF1-style code.  In ZF2 there is no pre-existing `public $view` property within the controller.

Comment: did that answer your question?

Comment: Hello @rockstarz, thanks for your fast reply! =D

I was going to explain again, but I think my answer was duplicate (I didn't saw the other question in my searches).

Again, thanks! =)

Comment: no problem.  zf2 is new for me as well, working on zf1 projects.  it's an adjustment but the learning curve doesn't seem too bad. If you feel the question was answered, please mark as correct.  thank you.

Comment: Thanks @rockstarz! =D Although you helped me a lot with your answer, I switched to CodeIgniter :P

Comment: LOL... no problem.  CodeIgniter is a nice framework with an easy learning curve.  If you're at all newer to frameworks, it's the best place to start imo.  If you're looking for another framework to experiment with you should also check out Yii and Symfony.